# carplay setRootTemplate crash (Allowed classes: (null))

Tags: xcode, ios15, carplay

I'm middle of transition from old carplay to new ios15 carplay.

I asked carplay entitlement to apple and have it now.

so I put some sample codes and run.

the code is

```swift
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    CPLogger.log("in templateApplicationScene didConnect")
    self.interfaceController = interfaceController
    let screen = CPListTemplate(title: "CarPlay", sections: [])
    self.interfaceController!.setRootTemplate(screen, animated: true, completion: { _,_ in
        })
    }
```

this method was hit so I think I dit it right from `Application Scene Manifest` of `info.plist`.

after that I faced crash and it said (last part is important in this case.)

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported object <CPListTemplate: 0x600001c79b80> <identifier: 8105D933-642B-4111-80D7-C910466237F5, userInfo: (null), tabTitle: (null), tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to setRootTemplate:animated:completion:. Allowed classes: (null)'
```

most search result has messages like `Thread 1: "Unsupported object <CPInformationTemplate: 0x6000012de010> <identifier: 3444D3F1-ECFF-4953-B543-459286E11371, userInfo: (null), tabTitle: (null), tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to setRootTemplate:animated:completion:. Allowed classes: {(\n    CPTabBarTemplate,\n    CPListTemplate,\n    CPGridTemplate,\n    CPAlertTemplate,\n    CPVoiceControlTemplate,\n    CPNowPlayingTemplate\n)}"`.

`Allowed classes` part has some information. But not mine.

I added proper info to an entitlements info
[image]

and I have a provisioning that includes carplay-audio option.
[image]

I have only one result that has 'Allowed classes: (null)' string which is https://githubmemory.com/@oguzhnatly

He said "Such a thing Allowed classes: (null) is almost impossible to happen. Normally, it must contain the name of CarPlay Templates."

and I don't have something useful.

now I'm completely lost...

HELP ME!

thanks

Comment: Same problem here, I cannot set the root template with a CPTabBarTemplate. Same error and `Allowed classes` is `(null)` too.

Comment: FYI, for me, the same code is working great on an intel cpu based macbook. M1 seems to be a problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started getting this after switching to a M1 MBP. Does not matter which type of template I try to set as root template. Still works on my old Intel Mac so it seems to be a M1 bug.

**EDIT: I FIXED IT!**

After skulking around the Apple Dev Forums I found someone with the same problem, but the problem only appeared after adding `arm64` to Excluded Architectures.

[image: Excluded Archs]

I too had added this to get the Google Places SDK to compile, so removing it was tricky. But Google has released a [beta version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/start#install-the-xcframework) of the SDK that is compatible with M1, but it needs to be installed manually or via Carthage. I removed the old SDK, removed `arm64` from `EXCLUDED_ARCHS`, installed the beta SDK and it worked! Now I can use the CarPlay Simulator on M1 without errors. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: confirmed... I ran my project from old iMac and it doesn't have this kind exception...

Comment: Dude!... thanks very much. You saved me quite some time. I spent a few hours tweaking entitlements plist, delegate methods, etc. In the end tried on my old intel MacBook and it just worked. Unfortunately I'm using a 3rd party SDK that doesn't support arm64 (and doesn't look like the provider is going to support it any time soon), so I ordered an aftermarket CarPlay display. Was going to do that anyway, just had to move the purchase a bit forward. Beats walking to my car every time to test on device. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

for update in M1 carplay simulator users.
Carplay document has been updated and there is new Carplay simulator in additional downloads in apple developer.

this is part of that documents

```
CarPlay Simulator
CarPlay Simulator is a standalone Mac app that simulates a complete car environment. CarPlay
Simulator is included in the Additional Tools for Xcode package which you can download from
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
Using CarPlay Simulator
Locate CarPlay Simulator in the Hardware folder, run it, and connect iPhone using a Lightning
to USB cable. CarPlay starts on iPhone just the same as if you had it connected to a real car.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of CarPlay application you have different templates that you can and cannot present. In the *Sections* section of the [CarPlay Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/carplay/documentation/CarPlay-App-Programming-Guide.pdf) you can see which templates are allowed for audio applications. Additionally, I think only a list or tab template is allowed as a root template. Which template are you trying to set as root?

Comment: I set CPListTemplate and carplay allows it. moreover, I think that 'allowed classes' has to show templates that i can use. the problem is it does not. it shows nothing (null).

Comment: You're right! Can you provide a sample project or compare your code to Apple's sample code? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating_carplay_with_your_music_app