I'm developing a CarPlay music app and encountering a crash when trying to present a Actionsheet
I'm developing a CarPlay music app and encountering a crash when trying to present a CPActionSheetTemplate using presentTemplate on the CPInterfaceController in iOS 15.5. The app functions as expected on iOS 17*.
Here is code which I'm using to present action sheet:
func showRequestSheet(_ id:String) {
    appPrint("Category Clicked: ", id)

    let actDismiss = CPAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
        self.interfaceController?.dismissTemplate(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    
    
    let actOk = CPAlertAction(title: "ok".translated, style: .default, handler: { action in
        if let category = CPHelper.shared.arrCategories.first(where: {return $0.id == id}) {
            self.interfaceController?.dismissTemplate(animated: true, completion: nil)
            CPHelper.shared.requestAudioAPI(category.name) { (isSuccess, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    let actDone = CPAlertAction(title: "e-mail_registration_password-strength-ok".translated, style: .default, handler: { action in
                        self.interfaceController?.dismissTemplate(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                    let alert = CPAlertTemplate(titleVariants: [err.translated], actions: [actDone])
                    self.interfaceController?.presentTemplate(alert, animated: true, completion: { isSuccess, error in
                        if let err = error {
                            appPrint("Category Success presentTemplate error: ", err)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
        
        let actionSheet = CPActionSheetTemplate(title: "auto_app_request-audio-carplay-title".translated, message: "auto_app_request-audio-carplay-text".translated, actions: [actOk,actDismiss])

        interfaceController?.presentTemplate(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: { isSuccess, error in
            if let err = error {
                appPrint("Category presentTemplate error: ", err)
            }
        })
        
    }

Crashing with below errror in iOS 15.5:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported object <CPActionSheetTemplate: 0x600000883720> <identifier: 154853B1-42C9-4A2E-A2AA-8431664FCDC4, userInfo: (null), tabTitle: (null), tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to presentTemplate:animated:completion:. Allowed classes: {(
    CPGridTemplate,
    CPListTemplate,
    CPNowPlayingTemplate,
    CPTabBarTemplate,
    CPAlertTemplate,
    CPVoiceControlTemplate
)}


Attaching screenshot which show me availability of actionsheet here: 
Thanks in advance!
It should be presented

You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

That's because you are using unsupported object on presentTemplate method in CPInterfaceController type CPActionSheetTemplate.
https://developer.apple.com/carplay/documentation/CarPlay-App-Programming-Guide.pdf
You have to use something from this list instead:
CPGridTemplate,
CPListTemplate,
CPNowPlayingTemplate,
CPTabBarTemplate,
CPAlertTemplate,
CPVoiceControlTemplate


You've just recited the runtime error without giving any further context. You also don't explain why the code works on iOS 17, but not iOS 15.

Good catch, thats because in ios 15.5 on that moment it was not supported. in the latest api apple added support of this template, this could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492765/carplay-setroottemplate-crash-allowed-classes-null

I suggest that you edit your answer to include the information that CPActionSheetTemplate is only permitted in audio CarPlay apps from iOS 17

To complete @swift2geek, the template you can use in a CarPlay app depends if your app is a Mudic app or a map app as defined in entitlement. This is a restriction by Apple.

Thanks for your response. I have edited the question to include the code I used to present the action sheet. Additionally, I have included a screenshot that indicates the component's availability.
